# ElasticsearchSinkConnector object mapping can't be changed from nested to non-nested

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm streaming my data from kafka topic into elasticsearch. But it's throwing this error from connector `{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"object mapping [search_data] can't be changed from nested to non-nested\"}`

But when I take the message from topic and add document manually using elasticsearch api, it is working fine.

Does kafka-connect-elasticsearch not support nested object type?

Please help me reply on this as I am stuck here for days.

**Elasticsearch version: 7.6.2**

**Kafka Connect Image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.2**

Below is my configuration for connector.

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "es_sink_products",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "localhost:9200",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "name": "product-elasticsearch-sink",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
}
```

Elasticsearch Schema

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "search_result_data": {
        "properties": {
          "product_id": {"type": "long"},
          "product_name": {"type": "text"},
        }
      },
      "search_data":{
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_parent": false,
        "properties": {
          "product_id": {"type": "long"},
          "full_text": {
            "type": "text",
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample message from topic `es_sink_products`

```
{
    "search_data": {
        "product_id": 1,
        "full_text": "Product 1"
    },
    "search_result_data": {
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Product Name 1"
    }
}
```

This is the full error from connector

`"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:561)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Bulk request failed: [{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"object mapping [search_data] can't be changed from nested to non-nested\"}]\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.handleMalformedDoc(BulkProcessor.java:479)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.execute(BulkProcessor.java:433)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:389)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:375)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkProcessorThread.run(BulkProcessor.java:370)\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at `type.name` in kafka connector configuration. Elasticsearch default type is `_doc`. Since I am using `kafka-connect` as a type, elasticsearch assume that I want to add another document type and clashes with existing `_doc` nested type.

By changing `"type.name": "_doc"` for connector configuration fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown when a non-nested mapping was previously set and you're trying to update that mapping w/ nested types.

What you could do now is:

1. Drop the index
2. Set the `nested` mapping (what you called `Elasticsearch Schema` above) once
3. Start the kafka stream **with the option `"schema.ignore": "false"`**

Reason: changing non-nested to `nested` is considered a 'breaking change' because of the way payloads get indexed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried above steps, it's throwing me same error. I checked the mapping - `search_data` field is already nested. And document can be inserted using Elasticsearch Put API. Error is thrown only when inserting from kafka-connect-elasticsearch.

Comment: it must have something to do w/ `schema.ignore` or a similar option.